# Program does not print two strings given by the user

Tags: arrays, c, char, scanf, declaration

The compiler does not print when I use more than one `scanf` function and stops after getting the inputs from user:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
   char firstName, lastName [20];
  
   //get first name from user
   printf("Your first name:");
   scanf("%s", &firstName);
   
   //get last name from user
   printf("Your last name:");
   scanf("%s", &lastName);
   
   //print the full name of the user
   printf("Your full name is: %s %s", firstName, lastName);
}
```

But a similar code with only one `scanf` function works perfectly fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
   char firstName [20];
  
   //get first name from user
   printf("Your first name:");
   scanf("%s", &firstName);
   
   //print the full name of the user
   printf("Your name is: %s %s", firstName);
}
```

I don't know how to handle this problem. Tried using different online compilers but I had the same error each time.

Comment: `char firstName[20], lastName[20];` If you only declare one variable per line you never run into problems like this where you assume something applies to more than one of the variables.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings before asking on Stack Overflow. These mistakes can easily be prevented.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in this declaration

```
char firstName, lastName [20];
```

the identifier `firstName` has the scalar type `char`.

It seems you mean

```
char firstName[20], lastName [20];
```

Or to avoid such a typo you could introduce a typedef alias for the array type as for example

```
typedef char CArray20[20];
```

and then write

```
CArray20 firstName, lastName;
```

Also you should write at least like

```
scanf("%s", firstName);
```

and

```
scanf("%s", lastName);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%s", &firstName);
```

and

```
scanf("%s", &lastName);
```

Though it will be more safer to write

```
scanf("%19s", firstName);
```

and

```
scanf("%19s", lastName);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I initially used the '&' because the code would just stop after the first `scanf` function otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

You are not initialising `firstName` like `lastName` . You can either use `malloc` or initialise it like you do with `lastName`

Comment: _initialize_ has a specific meaning in C.  Even if `firstName` was initialized like `char firstName = 0;`, it would still be a problem.  I suspect here you wanted to say "You are not _defining_ `firstName` like lastName".